# Anaconda navigator open virtual env jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtualenv

I am wondering why the following in anaconda navigator is happening.

Whereas by the base environement I can right click and launch Jupyter notebook:
[image]

This does not possible from other virtual environments does not work:

[image]

What should I do in order to be able to start also from all other environments Jupyter from the right click contextual menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to install Jupyter Notebook in the new environment, the base already has it installed by default. You can install it by choosing `Not Installed` option and searching for Jupyter Notebook.